# checking a file starts with a name in ftp location using java

Tags: java, ftp, filenames, apache-commons-net

Before downloading a file needs check whether the file(file name starts) exist or not:
I had a ftp location, it will generate a file in response to hitting a service(API). I need to check whether file exits or not in ftp location using a  starting characters of file name because it will append some data at end of file name.
Can any one help on this using java code with commons.net package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FTPFileFilter`

```
try {
    String filePattern = "prefix";
    FTPClient objFTPClient = new FTPClient();
    //objFTPClient - set username, password, host, etc...
    FTPFileFilter ftpFileFilter = new FTPFileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(FTPFile ftpFile) {
            return ftpFile.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(filePattern.toLowerCase());
        }
    };
    /* List of file that starts with your given prefix */
    FTPFile[] ftpFiles = objFTPClient.listFiles(remoteDirectory, ftpFileFilter);
}catch(Exception ex){ 
    ex.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    //close connection, etc....
}
```